# jquery 2 sets of radio boxes both selected but not with the same option

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-button

i have a list of questions which the user must answer, each question has 2 answers one being "most", and the other being "least", these are chosen from a group of 4 possibilities, for example:

Q: When working as part of a team, I am:

Careful
Determined
Exciting
Lazy

im trying to work out a way that when the user selects "careful" for the most option, he/she can not then select the same answer for "least"

once 2 answers are selected the script then displays the next question, this is where i am so far, the questions display properly, but the user is able to select the same answer for both "most" and "least" options, heres the code:

```
    <div id="question1">
    <label>Question 1:</label>

    <p class="most">Most</p>
    <label for="q1m1"><input type="radio" class="opt1" name="q1m" id="q1m1" value="10"> Enthusiastic</label>
    <label for="q1m2"><input type="radio" class="opt2" name="q1m" id="q1m2" value="8"> Bold</label>
    <label for="q1m3"><input type="radio" class="opt3" name="q1m" id="q1m3" value="6"> Diplomatic</label>
    <label for="q1m4"><input type="radio" class="opt4" name="q1m" id="q1m4" value="1"> Content</label>


    <p class="least">Least</p>
    <label for="q1l1"><input type="radio" class="opt1" name="q1l" id="q1l1" value="3"> Enthusiastic</label>
    <label for="q1l2"><input type="radio" class="opt2" name="q1l" id="q1l2" value="5"> Bold</label>
    <label for="q1l3"><input type="radio" class="opt3" name="q1l" id="q1l3" value="6"> Diplomatic</label>
    <label for="q1l4"><input type="radio" class="opt4" name="q1l" id="q1l4" value="0"> Content</label>


    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="q1_submit">Next</div>
    </div><!-- .buttons -->

</div><!-- #question1 -->   

<div id="question2" style="display: none;">
    <label>Question 2:</label>

    <p class="most">Most</p>
    <label for="q2m1"><input type="radio" class="opt1" name="q2m" id="q2m1" value="10"> Careful</label>
    <label for="q2m2"><input type="radio" class="opt2" name="q2m" id="q2m2" value="7"> Determined</label>
    <label for="q2m3"><input type="radio" class="opt3" name="q2m" id="q2m3" value="6"> Convincing</label>
    <label for="q2m4"><input type="radio" class="opt4" name="q2m" id="q2m4" value="3"> Good-natured</label>

    <p class="least">Least</p>
    <label for="q2l1"><input type="radio" class="opt1" name="q2l" id="q2l1" value="1"> Careful</label>
    <label for="q2l2"><input type="radio" class="opt2" name="q2l" id="q2l2" value="3"> Determined</label>
    <label for="q2l3"><input type="radio" class="opt3" name="q2l" id="q2l3" value="6"> Convincing</label>
    <label for="q2l4"><input type="radio" class="opt4" name="q2l" id="q2l4" value="9"> Good-natured</label>


    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="q2_prev">Previous</div>
        <div class="q2_submit">Next</div>
    </div><!-- .buttons -->

</div><!-- #question2 -->
```

and here is the jquery:

```
    $( ".q1_submit" ).click(function() {
    if($("input[name='q1m']::checked").length > 0 && $("input[name='q1l']::checked").length > 0){
        // go on with script
        $( "#question2" ).show( "slow" );
        $( "#question1" ).hide( "slow" );
     }else{
        // NOTHING IS CHECKED
        alert('Please chose one most and one least');
     }      
});

$( ".q2_prev" ).click(function() {
    $( "#question1" ).show( "slow" );
    $( "#question2" ).hide( "slow" );
});
```

so what i am trying to acheive is, if the classes of each group of radio buttons are the same, throw a validation error, is there a way off adding the class's to the if statement in the js script? something like:

if($("input[name='q1m'].class") == ($("input[name='q1l'].class") {
    ERROR
} ELSE {
    CARRY ON
}

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To make a radio button work, you need to give all options for which you only want one answer the same name.  If you reworked the names of your inputs, I think you might not need any jQuery to manage things.

I tried this:

```
  <label>Question 1:</label>

  <p class="most">Most</p>
  <label for="q1m1"><input type="radio" class="opt1"  name="q1-1" value="10"> Enthusiastic</label>
  <label for="q1m2"><input type="radio" class="opt2"  name="q1-2" value="8"> Bold</label>
  <label for="q1m3"><input type="radio" class="opt3"  name="q1-3" value="6"> Diplomatic</label>
  <label for="q1m4"><input type="radio" class="opt4"  name="q1-4" value="1"> Content</label>


  <p class="least">Least</p>
  <label for="q1l1"><input type="radio" class="opt1"  name="q1-1" value="3"> Enthusiastic</label>
  <label for="q1l2"><input type="radio" class="opt2"  name="q1-2" value="5"> Bold</label>
  <label for="q1l3"><input type="radio" class="opt3"  name="q1-3" value="6"> Diplomatic</label>
  <label for="q1l4"><input type="radio" class="opt4"  name="q1-4" value="0"> Content</label>
```

with no javascript, and When i click on Most Bold, then Least Bold, Most is unchecked.  Is that what you need?

You'll notice that I took out the ID parameter which you could put back in if you need it for something, but the key here is that `Enthusiastic` has the same name `q1-1` for both inputs, and `Bold` has the same name `q1-2` for both inputs.

And... if you go this route, and you change the names, make sure you update the form handler as the structure of the submitted data will be different.

What I didn't address here is any kind of JS validation to make sure all 4 categories get an answer.  If you need that too, then there will be some simple checking to make sure you have 4 checked inputs in the question div (or something like that).

Comment: thanks, but the logic is not right if i go down this route, as i want it so you can only answer one for most and one for lease, not one option for each, im looking at disabling one if the corresponding option has been clicked, think this might be a better way of doing it

Comment: Ah, so you need (sort of) both settings to change.  When I click choose "most enthusiastic" it should not allow me to choose any other items in "most" *and* it should not let me choose "least enthusiastic", is that correct?